# What is the significance of the "Standard Temperature" in Standard Enthalpies of Formation tables?

Tags: enthalpy

In my data book, there's a list of common compounds and their molar enthalpies of formation -- at 298.15 K. What's the meaning of this given temperature value (is it the final temperature of the compound in question?) and *how* does it affect the molar enthalpy of formation of a substance?

What, for example, does it mean when the molar enthalpy of formation of H<sub>2</sub>O(g) at 298.15 K is given as -241.8 kJ/mol, even though water should be in a liquid state at 298.15 K? And what would the molar enthalpy of formation of H<sub>2</sub>O(g) be at, for instance, 500 K?

Comment: Seems you forgot about water vapor.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Isn't water vapour H2O(g)?

Comment: Yes, so there's no problem with it at 25C

Comment: So is the standard temperature listed in these molar enthalpy tables the temperature of the system upon losing/gaining the given amount of enthalpy?

Comment: It's simply enthalpy in this temp. you have to pick temp. so...  Oh whatever, I need to go to sleep

Answer (score 3):

Most enthalpies (or themodynamic observables whatever their type) are not constant across the temperature range — not even across the range of one phase. So the enthalpy of vapourisation of water is different a $273\,\mathrm{K}$ from what it is at $295\,\mathrm{K}$ or $350\,\mathrm{K}$.

Of course, standard conditions have been defined. However, *the definition of standard conditions does not explicitly include temperature!* Likely because some wanted $273\,\mathrm{K}$, others wanted $295\,\mathrm{K}$. So the temperature at which a certain entropy is valid *must always be specified*.

Some books put a ‘standard temperature’ at the top and call that their specification.

Comment: See also [Notation for states and processes, significance of the word standard in chemical thermodynamics, and remarks on commonly tabulated forms of thermodynamic functions (IUPAC Recommendations 1981)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac198254061239): “The above definitions of standard states make no reference to fixed temperature. Hence, it is possible to have an infinite number of standard states of a substance as the temperature varies. (…)”